# Why is this regex hanging with two trailing back-slashes but works fine with just one?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following code using regex that hangs at the last line when I run it:

```
const char PathSeparator = '\\';
const string PathPrefix = "\\\\";

var reg = new Regex(string.Format("^{0}(([^{1}\r\n\v\f\u2028\u2029]+){1}?)+$", 
    Regex.Escape(PathPrefix), Regex.Escape(PathSeparator.ToString())));

var test = @"\\Inbox\Test123\Intermediate\3322FB69-FE3F-407E-9E15-584382A407A2\\";
var matches = reg.Matches(test);
var group = matches[0].Groups[2];
```

It works fine if I remove one of the final backslashes in `test`, e.g.

```
var test = @"\\Inbox\Test123\Intermediate\3322FB69-FE3F-407E-9E15-584382A407A2\";
```

Can someone please help me figure out why it's hanging?  I know I can set a timeout; that's not my question.

Comment: Note, I made a mistake pasting originally.  It works fine with one final backslash but hangs on two.  See edit.

Comment: Maybe its a problem with [backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), but I dont really see why this would bethe case

Comment: It is exactly that, excessive backtracking. The problem is the nested `+` quantifiers.

Comment: Please edit your title to be whatever you'd google for if you had this problem. Would you search for "Why is this regex hanging"?  Titles are really important for SEO purposes and so that other people who have your issue can find the answer quickly.

Comment: As a solution, using an atomic capturing group (`^\\\\(?>`...`)$`) works trivially. And there are other constructs that will also do the job (e.g. make the path separator unconditional and end the regex with a single optional [^...] group).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker -- I agree.  But the nature of a specific problem regarding regular expressions doesn't really lend itself to a title.  What would you suggest?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker -- How about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Now you have two problems

I have to begin this answer with the obligatory mention of the well-known [quote](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247). While regex is a powerful tool that can solve lots of problems (including this one) efficiently, it can also be a big source of trouble if you are not an expert on the subject and cause pain that would be entirely avoidable by going with lower-tech solutions.

In this instance you could trivially do the same job by splitting the input string on slashes, then validating each token produced on its own (yes, perhaps even with a regex). And it might actually be a smart move to do that because it would immensely reduce the complexity factor of the solution; something that will be quite valuable in the future when "a small tweak" (that increases complexity) is required.

That said, let's look at the interesting stuff: what happened?

### Why does it run forever?

Because of [excessive backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) caused by the nested `+` quantifiers. This will be easier to illustrate using a more tame sample input of

```
\\Foo\Bar\Baz\\
```

Let's see what the regex engine would attempt to match when fed this input.

1) First attempt: the innermost group matches `Foo\` and `Bar\` and `Baz\`. Further repetition fails because of the trailing `\`, then the end-of-input marker fails to match so the attempt is rejected and the engine backtracks.

*Note that if the trailing slash were not there, the regex engine would declare success and return at this point*.

2) Because the slash in the innermost group is optional, the next attempt is `Foo\`, `Bar\`, `Baz` which also obviously fails. More backtracking.

3) The next candidate matches four repetitions of the innermost group: `Foo\`, `Bar\`, `Ba` and `z\`. Fail, more backtracking.

From now on I will simply list the attempted matches by separating repetitions of the innermost group with a single space:

```
Foo\ Bar\ Ba z      (i.e. 4 repetitions of length 4, 4, 2, 1, and fails)
Foo\ Bar\ Ba
Foo\ Bar\ B az\
Foo\ Bar\ B az
Foo\ Bar\ B a
Foo\ Bar\
```

And so on.

The thing to note here is that it took an unreasonable number of attempts to even rule out that the trailing "Baz" segment can be part of a successful match: we had to consider "Baz", "Ba" + "z", "Ba", "B" + "az", "B" + "a", and "B"; in general, for a segment of length N the number of possibilities is N! (factorial). The factorial function's growth is beyond intuitive human comprehension [as Wikipedia illustrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

Since your sample input contains a final segment of length 36 it's obvious that attempting to match this regex with incorrectly formatted input will never finish.

### How to prevent this from happening?

In this case it's pretty simple. Since you know that with e.g. "Baz" there is no point in trying to split it into smaller chunks if matching it as a whole fails (because these chunks would need to be separated by a slash, which we already know they are not because slashes are not an allowed part of the attempted match), use an atomic capturing group:

```
var reg = new Regex(string.Format(
    "^{0}(?>([^{1}\r\n\v\f\u2028\u2029]+{1}?))+$",
    Regex.Escape(PathPrefix),
    Regex.Escape(PathSeparator.ToString())));
```

This will backtrack only 1 time instead of N! for each path segment on an unsuccessful match, reducing the time to fail to practically zero.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation.  For what it's worth, I did start out going the non-regex route but it quickly became obvious I'd have to deal with a variety of possible "bad" inputs -- e.g. path prefix was left off, path started with 3 or more separator characters, path contained consecutive separator characters internally, etc.  If I just split on the separator character, I'd have to deal with my own form a back-tracking in a sense as I looped through the resulting array.  You can see how it could be messy....regex seemed like (and still does seem like) the winning approach.